# strange behaviour Pinging Public IP

Tags: router, ping, icmp

I've tried this on 2 different networks:

- Set router to respond to ping on internet port.
- Lookup public IP on www.whatsmyip.com
- Use PuTTy to ssh into another server and pinging the public IP from there.

In one network 1 this works, in network 2 it won't. So the question is. What can cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The public IP address (the address that external sites see your requests coming from, i.e. what whatismyip will tell you) may not be one that the router is directly reachable on, for example if [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) is deployed.

ISPs may use CGNAT if they don't have enough IPv4 addresses, in order to share a single address between multiple clients.

One way to tell if this is happening would be to compare whatismyip.com to the address the router says it has on its WAN/internet interface. If they're different (and the router is connected straight to the ISP), it's probably CGNAT at play.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is exactly what happens. On the network i called network 2 i see an address on the WAN interface to some address 10.x.x.x (which is not what's seen when checking on whatsmyip.com). Is there anything I can do to ping my router in this case?

Comment: Yes, that definitely looks like CGNAT since 10.0.0.0/8 is one of the [private address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). You can check if your ISP has an option to get a static public IP address (they may charge extra for it, if they offer it at all), or you could use a VPN setup of some sort to make it publicly accessible.

Comment: Thanks, I Will look into VPN then. Or just settle now that I now why this happend.